# Deploy WPF Application with SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sql-server-2008, windows

I'm using visual studio 2012. I created a WPF app for a client using service based database and  published the app but it fails to access database. Now i have installed Sql server 2008. Please guide me through the process on how to deploy my app using sql server and what changes i should make in my connection string and app.config or any other change i need to make. I have googled and searched on stack overflow for two days but could find any detailed solution.

Comment: So you are saying you have an .exe application used by end-users that connects to the database directly? and you want to give users the connection string to your database?

Comment: yes exactly, the connection string is according to my computer and they do not have sql server or visual studio installed, is there any way they can access that database file packaged with my setup.exe

Comment: Is that one central database? or one DB per user and users always keep their own data?

Comment: actually it is for only one client therefore one DB with three tables for only one user.

Comment: Most likely your local PC is not available from outside the network - you need to do port forwarding, firewalls, etc - to make sure SQL Server is accessible to the outside world. But this is a bad practice and dangerous. Or you can rewrite the app to use local storage, like SQLite - this will remove the need for a connection to your PC

Comment: I already made a local database, but the client cannot access it. That's why i want to deploy it using sql server. I want to create a installer using Install Shield or Advanced installer which will install all pre-requisites like .Net Framework 4.0 and sql server 2008 in his computer and deploy my app so that he don't have to bother about anything.

Comment: "Local storage" - local to the user. Look into alternatives to SQL Server, i.e. SQLite. I'd hate if applications try to install SQL Server on my machine.

Comment: thanks @trailmax i'm looking for better alternatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For only one PC, there is no need for a service based database. Because for service based database, There should be always a background service running to handle to requests. I came across the same issue when I had to deploy the WPF application to client's machine.

Unless you have a multi-user app and a need for a central database, Your best choice is to use SQLite. It is one disk file that does not need any service running for connection.

The connection string just have to match the place of the SQLite file. You can refer to this link for a start.

[Sqlite with WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153407/WPF-and-SQLite-Database)

Also SQlite supports both DB first and Code First approaches of Entity Framework and also LINQ to SQL. You will find it a bit hard to convert but it is worth it. As it is not something I can tell in just one answer, I will try to maybe write an article on C# corner and let you know.

Comment: your answer is most relevant, as u advised i tried to set up sqlite on my vs2012 but things are still complicated for me. I will look forward for your article.

Comment: Please describe which ORM model you are using ? Linq to sql, EF or simply ADO.NET ?

Comment: I am using simple ADO.NET but i also know EF.

Comment: Ok. I will try to explain both methods in my article. I will give you a link here when I do

Comment: I have sent u a message on facebook. Is it possible u can help me there? :D

Comment: Sure. But still I might write article and paste that here so people can see